# как сделать что бы $.each делал итерацию с рандомным промежутком времени?

Tags: javascript, jquery, таймер

```js
    var $switch = jQuery('.switch');

    var open = function () {

        $switch.each(function(i ,v) {

            jQuery(v).slideDown(400).animate({ opacity: 1 } ,600)
        
        })


    }


open()
```

```css
.switch {
  
  display: none;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switch">switch 1</div>
                <div class="switch">switch 2</div>
                <div class="switch">switch 3</div>
                <div class="switch">switch 4</div>
                <div class="switch">switch 5</div>
```

сейчас все `div switch` появляются одновременно , но как сделать что бы они появлялись поочередно **с рандомным промежутком времени ?**

и что бы я мог ограничивать этот промижуток

Comment: Кто то старается ускорить цикл, а кто-то замедлить))

Comment: @Vearo в моем случае замедлить  причем сильно ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как то так?

```js
var switches = [...$('.switch')];

var open = function () {
    $(switches.shift()).slideDown(400).animate({opacity: 1}, 600*Math.random())    
    switches.length && setTimeout(open, 300*Math.random())
}

open()
```

```css
.switch {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switch">switch 1</div>
<div class="switch">switch 2</div>
<div class="switch">switch 3</div>
<div class="switch">switch 4</div>
<div class="switch">switch 5</div>
```

Ну и вариант когда это вынесено в функцию:

```js
function each(els, t, callback) {
    callback($(els.shift()));
    els.length && setTimeout(e => each(...arguments), t*Math.random());
}

each([...$('.switch')], 300, function(el) {
  el.slideDown(400).animate({opacity: 1}, 600*Math.random()); 
})
```

```css
.switch {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switch">switch 1</div>
<div class="switch">switch 2</div>
<div class="switch">switch 3</div>
<div class="switch">switch 4</div>
<div class="switch">switch 5</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var $switch = jQuery('.switch');

var open = function() {

  var time = 0;
  $switch.each(function(i, v) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      jQuery(v).slideDown(400 * (i + 1)).animate({opacity: 1}, 600);
    }, time);
    time += 400 + Math.random() * 500;
  });
}

open();
```

```css
.switch {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switch">switch 1</div>
<div class="switch">switch 2</div>
<div class="switch">switch 3</div>
<div class="switch">switch 4</div>
<div class="switch">switch 5</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы запустите анимацию через [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), то он запустится через определённое время (например рандомное). А [промисы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) помогут вам запустить таймауты последовательно.